# Setting up header and getting JSON using $http

Tags: json, angularjs, http, header

Why is this header code not working? If I do not put the header, only the JSON, the table works. But if I am going to set it on the site header to get the JSON, it doesn't work. Is this a working query? Do I have a missing delimiter?

```
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
$http("http://staging.api.sample.com/activity.json", {header: {Authorization: 'NkgjkdleLKSldksLKSd'}}) .success(function(response) {
    debugger
    $scope.members=response.events;
     $scope.totals = response.paging;
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$http accepts `config` object only

There are sortcut function such as `get`, which take first parameter as url and second as `config`.

You invocation should look like

`$http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/activity.json", {headers: {Authorization: 'NkgjkdleLKSldksLKSd'}})`

Also make note it is **headers** not **header**.

Comment: yeah i tried d other shortcut function for 'get' like               $http({url: 'http://staging.api.sample.com/activity.json', method: 'get'})     nothing happens. i dunno why isn't working ,

Comment: finally it works , yea ,, you're right . it's headers not header , i add 's' and it works , haha , tnx men!